# Partial anonymous record in F#

Tags: f#

How do I type let's say a function that takes a record that has a field `a` and **any other field**?

Is some equivalent of this *Standard ML* function possible in F#?

```ml
fun f {a: string, ...} = "Hello" ^ a;
```

Tried the following but these don't seem to be syntactically valid:

```fs
let f (r: {|a: string; _|}) = impl;
let g (r: {|a: string; ...|}) = impl;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of constraint with Statically Resolved Type Parameters like so:

```
let inline f< ^T when ^T: (member a: string)> (r: ^T) = ()

f {| a = "yeet" |} // compiles
f {| a = "yeet"; b = "yote" |} // compiles
f {| b = "yote" |} // error
```

Note that this isn't *just* for anonymous records. It will hold true for any type that has a member with the specified signature.

I also like to hide these things behind a module and extract the nasty SRTP stuff into an active pattern like so:

```
module M =
    let inline private (|HasName|) x = (^a : (member Name: string) x)

    let inline printName (HasName name) = printfn $"{name}"

type Person1 = { Name: string; Age: int }
type Person2 = { Name: string; Age: int; IsFunny: bool }

type Name(name) =
    member _.Name = name

let p1 = { Name = "Phillip"; Age = 30 }
let p2 = { Name = "Phillip"; Age = 30; IsFunny = false }
let nm = Name "Phillip"

M.printName p1
M.printName p2
M.printName nm
```

This has the benefit of hiding the details of how you get the constraint "lined up correctly" and lets you easily re-use the signature in other things you want to publicly expose.

Comment: It's awesome but I don't understand how the name are returned from the active pattern HasName. Have you some link explaining this syntax?

Comment: This is SRTP "calling" syntax. It's effectively saying, "call the `HasName` member on `x`". But the syntax is uhh, kinda obtuse.